Multiple executables using electron-builder
I have written an electron app that shows notifications to my users. I have packaged this app using electron-builder / electron-forge. I also have written code for the app to have a screensaver feature where it creates a frameless full screen window and that shows a slide show of images. I manage the idle state of the user using powermonitor. But powermonitor will report idle if the user is playing a media or is in a Teams call or displaying a presentation on PowerPoint and have not given user input through keyboard or mouse. I would like to know if there is a way of packaging my screensaver as a sperate exe in the same project which I can later install as a scr on windows using my installer.
I have tried different configurations for powermonitor, I don't want to use graph api to check if the user is on a Teams call. I can check for active or in focus windows to see if Teams or PowerPoint or any mediaplayer is active but that doesn't seem like 100% solution to my problem.
